# How do you index a text column in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In MySQL Key Length is added as a type-modifier and placed in parenthesis colname(), one can provide it to CREATE INDEX like this,

```
CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx ON foo ( bar(500) );
```

**scenario :**

***Mysql custom db api function:***

```
def add_index(self, doctype, fields, index_name=None):
    """Creates an index with given fields if not already created.
    Index name will be `fieldname1_fieldname2_index`"""
    index_name = index_name or self.get_index_name(fields)
    table_name = 'tab' + doctype
    if not self.has_index(table_name, index_name):
        self.commit()
        self.sql("""ALTER TABLE `%s`
            ADD INDEX `%s`(%s)""" % (table_name, index_name, ", ".join(fields)))
```

***using the above for mysql as;***

```
hotelier.db.add_index("Item", ["route(500)"])
```

***postgresql custom db api function:***

```
def add_index(self, doctype, fields, index_name=None):
    """Creates an index with given fields if not already created.
    Index name will be `fieldname1_fieldname2_index`"""
    index_name = index_name or self.get_index_name(fields)
    table_name = 'tab' + doctype

    self.commit()
    self.sql("""CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "{}" ON `{}`("{}")""".format(index_name, table_name, '", "'.join(fields)))
```

**How to call the same thing in postgresql ?**

```
hotelier.db.add_index("Item", ["route(500)"])
```

Comment: What kind of query or WHERE condition are you trying to support with that index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see the edits

Comment: I don't see any SQL query. Indexes are created to support specific queries, not just out of the blue. You will need to show us the actual SQL code you are running. The obvious answer is `create index on foo (left(bar, 500))`